# Load testing via JMeter for asp.net web service so how to handle vivewstate,viewstate1,viewstate2 and eventvalidation things for end to end flow

Tags: asp.net, jmeter, performance-testing

steps followed by me:

1. create Thread Group->http request default
2. added recording controller in thread group
3. added view result tree

After that-
WorkBench-

1. HTTP proxy server
2. Added listener-View result tree

I recorded the script
but I want to know how I correlate the all pages or flow so I got actual result
Like from

1. login(get)-Login(post) then
2. Calculte something in another page
3. then click on continue button and we got new page
4. and fill the details and again click on continue button the some thing save in database
5. After that redirect to payment gateway and after that we got final result

So please let me explain ho to do load testing for this flow

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you need to go trough the following articles:

- [Correlation in JMeter](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html) in general
- [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) in particular

The whole idea is

1. To make first HTTP request to the very first page
2. Extract dynamic parameters and save them into JMeter Variables via one of the following PostProcessors:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)
3. Populate second HTTP Request using JMeter Variables from step 2
4. If you need to go further repeat steps 1-3 for 2nd request

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T I follow the steps as you told- 1.Via First HTTP (GET)request I Extract the dynamic values(viewstste,viewstate1,viewstate2 and EventValidation) via Regular Expression Extractor and pass it to 2nd HTTP request 2. Then I go for run then I got blank page on 2nd HTTP request but in request I got response from server is 200 OK. and same I done on next request and response but I got blank page only. why this is showing blank page Is there any thing missing from my side ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to play with `Redirect Automatically` and/or `Follow redirects` parameters. It's hard to say what is wrong unless you share request and responses details